# What went wrong at Matan Torah - adjusting G-d's presentation to the Jewish people?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, parashas-yisro, kabbalat-hatorah

> וְכָל־הָעָם רֹאִים אֶת־הַקּוֹלֹת וְאֶת־הַלַּפִּידִם וְאֵת קוֹל הַשֹּׁפָר וְאֶת־הָהָר עָשֵׁן וַיַּרְא הָעָם וַיָּנֻעוּ וַיַּעַמְדוּ מֵרָחֹק׃ וַיֹּאמְרוּ אֶל־מֹשֶׁה דַּבֵּר־אַתָּה עִמָּנוּ וְנִשְׁמָעָה וְאַל־יְדַבֵּר עִמָּנוּ אֱלֹהִים פֶּן־נָמוּת׃
>
> All the people witnessed the thunder and lightning, the blare of the horn and the mountain smoking; and when the people saw it, they fell back and stood at a distance. “You speak to us,” they said to Moses, “and we will obey; but let not God speak to us, lest we die.” ([Ex 20](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.20.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

The Gemmorah clarifies that the people heard only two out of the decalogue straight from G-d and then retreated to a great distance and the rest of the commandments they asked Moses to intermediate as they could not bear G-d's presence.

As the Torah depicts it IMHO, the incident seems unplanned and unfortunate.

Why couldn't G-d adjust Himself or people's perception that Matan Torah would not end so abruptly?

Comment: I think there's a Midrash that explains that when they initially approached Mt. Sinai, they were :angelic", and probably able to bear the loud voices. Then, something happened. On a "simpler" level, perhaps they really didn't know what to expect. I mean, thunder, lightening and a loud shofar, I guess people can bear. But God's loud booming voice? I guess that would scare anybody, no?

Comment: @DanF I agree completely about the people, but what about G-d? Did He "plan" it to end so? Couldn't He manipulate it differently?

Comment: It might have been a nisayon, to see if the Jews were trusting enough that they won’t be scared of dying, in which case they failed.